# Why keyframed animation of linked object is not saved?

Tags: keyframes

I've Objects I linked from one file to another. When I make keyframes, save, then revert, the keyframes are gone.
So I copied the Objects to a fresh project.(I used two blender windows, that's considered appending still?) Then linked to a new project and it worked.

Can anyone tell me the difference between these files?

Broken File

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15WJkl-9PXkAo9BYnJF6GqM5l9vsFl4OR/view?usp=sharing

Working File

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gy5Eo0AJcIGgfwd-CFvrwWk1HopLAUjX/view?usp=sharing

A video to help understand.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QGfcNyjZzMhZYZW2YmG5dKUAsSdK8pzF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I create a new file. Then link the Collection "BROWN_HAIR_GIRL" from of these files that I provided. I next create Library overrides. Then I pose the model and create keyframes. The broken file won't save the the keyframes in this new file. super strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files differs in more aspects, but one that cause saving the keyframes is your "CRUMPLE" action saved in your "broken" file.

[image]

There is several ways to fix it:

- Delete this *Action* in your original file before *Linking* or
- Manually set **Make Library Override** by right click on item in *Outliner* of the file or
- Go to *Dope Sheet* editor switch to *Action* editor and click on chain icon to make it local or click on X icon to delete *Action*

[image]

Note: When you use "Link" operator (to bring some elements from another blend file) you can't modify them. For that blender use **Library Override** to make it happen. Any linked element in Outliner that is linked from external directory is using "chain" icon to indicate that. To be able to manipulate with linked object you have to **Add Library Override**, that creates something like information layer that stores changes from original.

I have never used *Library Override* before so I'm not experienced here ... but for some reason *Actions* and *Materials* are kept *Linked* for **Make Library Override Hierarchy** command by default. If it is a bug or expected behaviour ... I don't know (probably in common use you don't want to modify those). Anyway as I wrote you have to delete or **Override** specific items manually.

Comment: Ok, that worked... Getting rid of that action is bad. Can you explain why the other file works w/o doing that? I checked it and it's still linked and works. Thanks for fixing my grammar.

Comment: You don't have to get rid of it if you need it ... you just need to make it Override because like now it is blocked by Link assignment (WORK one has no this Action that is why it works).

Comment: @jitone1 If it worked for you consider mark answer as Accepted https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour to keep this site organised. Thank you

Comment: Ok. I had to look closely at my file to understand. But I understand now. There was an action in the Action Editor and I had to "push down" to save it. That cleared the action editor for changes in the linked file. Thanks. Can you help me with a similar problem?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218801/changing-a-linked-objects-material