# Changing a Linked object's Material

Tags: materials, linked-data

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cRT59awRpqGY_euLlEerg1DIejJGO5WH).

[Video Explanation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fG3cKq97MTmKvS_ZNQi7mpwf_6XQiF8_).

I made a collection with an object parented to a bone. The bone has a property in pose mode and drives a color change in the material of the object. When I link this collection to another blend file and save the property stops working.
How can I correct this? I need to be able to do this w/o changing the material and adding a driver to it every time I open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to *Outliner*, right click over *Material* item and choose **Resync Library Override** it brings driver to work, but after reopening file it is not working again and I had to Resync again.

From video it looks like you are using 2.92 in this version when saved&reopen (or your Revert), Material became *Linked* (chain icon) for some reason, that is why driver is not working. It is the same issue like I noted in [your previous Q](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218504/2214) with Action. You have to right click on *Material* item and manually **Add Library Override** first (so it became chain with arrow icon). Than Resync LO.

[image]

In 2.93 your driver is not working from beginning, even in this version *Material* has LO icon it is not working anyway and *Resync LO* is needed as well.

Note: I have zero experiences with LO as mentioned, but it seems to me like a bug or not working feature since LO is very new to blender, so it can be just a corner case yet in development. Try to post it as a bug and mention bug report link here in a comment, so others can follow developers statement of this thing. Thank you

---

*In latest experimental build 2.93 I noticed under User Preferences > Experimental ... there is **Override Auto Resync** with a link to https://developer.blender.org/T83811 so you can get more info. But seems like not covering your issue yet (from what I tried - still manually).*

*If someone smarter here can explain more.*

Comment: Thank you. I'll take you advice and post it as a bug.

Comment: Even the link to devs is closed they usually react for a new reasonable comments there, so ... I would suggest to write your issue with driver there and see what they think about it before you post a bug ... probably it is a missing feature than a bug. Like here when I searched for "Library Override Drivers" here is one of them https://developer.blender.org/T70319 ... marked as "TO DO".